# Compute the push-forward of a vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

Let $G$ be the group of matrix of the form $$
M(u, v, w)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\cos w & \sin w & 0 & u \\
-\sin w & \cos w & 0 & v \\
0 & 0 & 1 & w \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right), \quad u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}
$$
and $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(4, \mathbb{R}),(u, v, w) \mapsto M(u, v, w)$.

1. Compute
   $$
   \sigma_{*}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right), \quad \sigma_{*}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right), \quad \sigma_{*}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\right)
   $$

---

Let $q=(u,v,w),$  $$\left(\sigma_*{\frac{\partial}{\partial u}}\right)_{M(q)}=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} \sigma(q+te_1)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$

$$\left(\sigma_*{\frac{\partial}{\partial v}}\right)_{M(q)}=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} \sigma(q+te_2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$
and
$$\left(\sigma_*{\frac{\partial}{\partial w}}\right)_{M(q)}=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} \sigma(q+te_3)=\begin{pmatrix} -\sin w& \cos w&0&0\\-\cos w&-\sin w&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Is this true? Any help is appreciated !

Comment: It seems ok to me.

Comment: Thank you so much !